# undefined data when posting to php by ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

this is my `javascript` code

```
    var ActivityType ='d';
    var TotalActivities = 2;
    function marker(ActivityType,TotalActivities)

    {

    var dataTosend='typ='+ActivityType+'&total='+TotalActivities;

    $.ajax({

    url: 'activity.php',

    type: 'POST',

    data:dataTosend,

    async: true,

    success: function (data) {

    alert(data)

    },

    });

    }
marker();
```

this is my `activity.php` file

```
<?php
echo $_POST['typ'];
echo $_POST['total'];

?>
```

when i call `marker();` in `js` i got `undefined undefined` in `alert`

why does it says undefined data ?

but there is no error means `typ ,& total` parameter are reaching there

but why it says undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing in the variables as parameters when you call `marker()`.

The arguments in the function are same name as the outer variables so inside the function scope, the argument versions are undefined and the outer variables are shadowed by the same name arguments

Try calling:

```
marker(ActivityType,TotalActivities);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have call marker function the arguments are missing.

```
marker(ActivityType,TotalActivities);
```

you can also use this format when you have send the data using ajax.

```
    data:{typ:ActivityType,total:TotalActivities}
```